# Replacing lock cylinder and ignition starter switch but what about codes/keys?

Tags: ignition, ignition-key, beetle

I have a question about a 2008 Beetle, 2.5l , SE

We need to replace the lock cylinder and ignition starter switch. The place is asking us about 460$ in labor, and the parts are almost 300$. We already paid 100$ in diagnosis, so if we want to go ahead it will be 660$

Do we have to program the codes for the key ? 
Can we order the parts online(ask the company to program them by giving them our VIN nr) and have a local mechanic replace this ?
I was thinking to order it online (200$ total part), have a local mechanic replace it, maybe up to 150-200$, and some local dealership to program the keys (but i don't know how much this might cost)

How much does programming usually costs ? We are looking for the best solution to minimizing the 700+ cost, and any advice is welcome

Comment: You can just call the dealership and ask how much it costs to program a key. You can ask online parts shops if they can program new keys for you by calling or emailing their customer service.

Comment: I called an auto lock smith and they told me it's cost 160$ to program it. Is that price normal ?

Comment: It's normal for that auto lock smith. Compare it to whatever price you get when you ask the dealer. Also http://cars.costhelper.com/replace-ignition-lock-cylinder-cost.html.

Comment: Oh well, it seems in the end it will cost me 500. 200 parts, 150 to replace the cylinder, and to program it 160$.